# What is the proper way to write code for transactions?

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, transactions, deadlock

When doing transactions from multiple threads or processes to the same database and tables is it custom to expect an error of the type:

> Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Coming from MySQL?
My understanding is that this does not indicate a deadlock as also the case of blocking due to an expensive operation.
In my case I noticed in a code structure like the following:

```
BEGIN  
DELETE FROM TableA where pk = X  
DELETE FROM TableC where colA = X  
DELETE FROM TableD where colA = X  
DELETE FROM TableE where colA = X  
DELETE FROM TableF where colA = X  
COMMIT
```

For more context I wanted to delete from these tables so to be faster I separate the deletes in many threads by assigning batches of PK instead of doing it via a single thread sequentially.
So basically as far as I can tell there can be no deadlocking (please correct me if I am wrong).
So the issue I think is that one of the threads is blocked for too long trying to do a delete.
It seems (according to the error msg also) that I would some how need to handle this case in the application level.
So my question is: When writing code that does transactions does one normally need to expect such an error and eg wait for a few seconds and retry the transactions a couple of times and then possibly give up?
I am not sure if this is how one would normally code for transactions or not.
(Note: I am tagging as Java although it it not a Java question as it is my language of preference).

Comment: Is there a reason not to use foreign keys and cascading deletes ?

Comment: @X.L.Ant:That is the current design and I can not change it. I would assume though that the same issue would arise as the cascading delete is also "lengthy" operation

Comment: Yes I agree. It was just out of curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct -- this is not the same thing as a deadlock.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout

The `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` system variable determines how long InnoDB will wait to acquire a row lock before giving up.

Your multiple threads are most likely having to wait on each other, so in this case, you might reconsider whether multiple threads is a useful approach for what you're trying to accomplish.

Typically, these error are signs of a problematic condition in your application, since it normally would be a sign of trouble if rows were locked for so long -- the best practice in transactional operations is to get in, do work, and get out again (commit or rollback) as quickly as possible.  Obviously, when doing operations on a large number of rows, that's not possible, so lock waits become more likely, as other transactions that need the same exclusive row or index locks will have to wait.

Comment: But I don't do operations in large number of rows.I have 20 threads that each delete a row from each of the 4 tables in a single transaction. I.e. I have 20000 primary keys for each of the 20 threads and each run the transaction in the snippet of the OP for each one of the PKs.

Comment: Interesting.  How long does a single one of those transactions take, if run by itself?

Comment: I have not added any timers but looking at the console what I log I can see that according to the logs each thread seems that it deletes a "logical" record i.e. finished the transaction in less than a second. Of course the logs are "scrabbled" with the threads writing one after the other